# Cannot Edit Rows in GridView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, gridview

I'm trying to retrieve 2 tables' data from Microsoft SQL Server to a GridView control. So far I am able to display the whatever I want in GridView control. However, I would like to make it **Editable** for the users, and I have a **small problem** with that.

This is my **GridView** control source code as below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style36" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
        CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="SID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SID" HeaderText="Student ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="S_FName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="S_FName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="S_LName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="S_LName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Atd_Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Atd_Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Atd_InTime" HeaderText="In Time" SortExpression="Atd_InTime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Atd_OutTime" HeaderText="Out Time" SortExpression="Atd_OutTime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Atd_Comment" HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="Atd_Comment" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

As you can see above, I am using **SqlDataSource1** to retrieve data to GridView:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SAOS1ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT attendance.Atd_Date, attendance.Atd_InTime, attendance.Atd_OutTime, attendance.Atd_Comment, 
        attendance.Status, student.SID, student.S_FName, student.S_LName FROM student LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance ON student.SID = attendance.SID 
        AND attendance.Atd_Date = @Atd_Date LEFT OUTER JOIN class ON student.CID = class.CID WHERE (class.CID = @CID)" 
        UpdateCommand="updatetable1" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="datepicker" Name="Atd_Date" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LabelClassID" Name="CID" PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Atd_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Atd_Date" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Time" Name="Atd_InTime" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Time" Name="Atd_OutTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Atd_Comment" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Status" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="S_FName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="S_LName" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

For the **UPDATE** statement, I am using Stored Procured called **updatetable1**:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[updatetable1]
(
    @Atd_ID int,
    @Atd_Date date,
    @Atd_InTime time(7),
    @Atd_OutTime time(7),
    @Atd_Comment varchar(50),
    @Status varchar(50),
    @SID int,
    @S_FName varchar(50),
    @S_LName varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE attendance SET Atd_Date=@Atd_Date, Atd_InTime=@Atd_InTime, Atd_OutTime=@Atd_OutTime, Atd_Comment=@Atd_Comment, Status=@Status where Atd_ID=@Atd_ID
UPDATE student SET S_FName=@S_FName, S_LName=@S_LName WHERE SID=@SID
END
RETURN
```

When I click on **Edit link** in GridView, the columns from table `student` such as **SID, S_FName & S_LName** are successfully updated.

But the rest of the columns from table `attendance` **cannot be successfully updated**. The changes are remaining the same. Please HELP

Comment: Your result set doesn't include `Atd_ID` so there is no valid value to pass to the stored procedure.

Comment: @SeanLange I would like to make all of the columns from table **attendance** are editable to users. What do you mean only updates two columns? I have SET multiple columns in SP right?

Comment: @Crowcoder But I can't really update column **Atd_ID** because it's an identity column

Comment: You don't need to update it, but it must be in your dataset (part of the `SelectCommand`) if you are going to pass it as a parameter to the procedure. If you know how to trace your database take a look at what is executing.

Comment: @Crowcoder What do you mean? Can you explain in detail? You mean that I have to change `SelectCommand` in SqlDataSource?

Comment: Think about it, how would the datasource know what id to send to the update command? I think all you need to do is literally add `Atd_ID` to the select statement: `SelectCommand="SELECT attendance.Atd_ID, attendance.Atd_Date, ......`

Comment: You may also need to add it to DataKeyNames. I don't remember the specifics of WebForms (or I would have written an answer) but I can see there is no way for your command to know what id to use.

Comment: @Crowcoder It works, thank you for your advice! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `GridView` definition, there's a property named `DataKeyNames` where you can set the name of key field(s) which enables automatic update/delete for rows contained inside it. Here is brief explanation from [`DataKeyNames` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_GridView_DataKeyNames):

> You should only set this property to the field or fields that are
>   required to uniquely identify each row; for example, the ID column if
>   an integer value uniquely identifies each row. You must set the
>   DataKeyNames property in order for the automatic update and delete
>   features of the GridView control to work.

Based from current `GridView` state, probably you might require both primary and foreign keys of `attendance` and `student` table to enable automatic update as described above:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style36" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
              DataKeyNames="Atd_ID,SID" ...>
</asp:GridView>
```

Also remember to add `Atd_ID` as primary key of `attendance` table to the result set of `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SAOS1ConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT attendance.Atd_ID, ..., student.SID, ..." 
            UpdateCommand="updatetable1" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```